# Is there a physically realizable inductive turing machine that can solve Hilbert's $10$th problem and can it overcome Church-Turing Hypothesis?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, algorithms, big-picture, automata-theory

There is a claim on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-recursive_algorithm#Inductive_Turing_machines that 'Simple inductive Turing machines are equivalent to other models of computation such as general Turing machines of Schmidhuber, trial and error predicates of Hilary Putnam, limiting partial recursive functions of Gold, and trial-and-error machines of Hintikka and Mutanen.[1] More advanced inductive Turing machines are much more powerful. There are hierarchies of inductive Turing machines that can decide membership in arbitrary sets of the arithmetical hierarchy(Burgin 2005). In comparison with other equivalent models of computation, simple inductive Turing machines and general Turing machines give direct constructions of computing automata that are thoroughly grounded in physical machines'.

Wiki also says these are different from infinite time Turing machines.

Are inductive turing machines different from turing machines with oracles?

Are inductive turing machines physically realizable (at least in the same sense of realizaility of Turing machines as Intel processors with bounded RAM and one that degrades over time)?

Can inductive turing machines solve the halting problem (essentially Hilbert's $10$th as well)?

Please refer here for overcoming Church-Turing Hypothesis with Inductive Turing machines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-recursive_algorithm#Relation_to_the_Church.E2.80.93Turing_thesis.

Here is another article (published in communications of the ACM and well cited) http://www.columbia.edu/itc/hs/medinfo/g6080/misc/p82-burgin.pdf.

Comment: Computability theory is not really about what is "physically realizable." Are Turing machines themselves physically realizable? No, because once the paper tape becomes large enough, it will have to be in orbit somehow and will inevitably tear; or if it is organized compactly somehow, then it will collapse into a stellar mass or black hole from its own gravity. It seems that there will be a finite physical upper bound for the size of a Turing machine that can actually operate, and so the physically operable Turing machines do not constitute a Turing-complete model of computation.

Comment: Not to mention the further complicating issue that according to some physical theories, the physical universe has finite size, matter and energy.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Or thermodynamics - Turing machines aren't supposed to degrade/fall apart! (And of course [black hole computing](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mapdw/borel2.1.pdf) is similarly rough on the hardware.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins fair enough but Burgin claims inductive machines are physically realizable in every way that we all think our computers are Turing machines and so the query 'can the Hilbert 10th problem be solved by these machines?' is still valid provided if there is any reason at all to believe these machines differ from Turing machines with oracles (which are in no way realizable in sense I just mentioned). Refer comment here by Burgin http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2007/03/inductive-turing-machines.html starting from 'Dear Lance,'. Note DARPA funds superrecursive algorithms.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins so do you agree that these 'inductive machines are different from oracle turing machines" but "much more powerful than turing machines (capable of solving Hilbert's $10$th)"? Note wiki clearly states these machines are DIFFERENT from infinite time turing machines that you talk about. This is my concern. I do not understand.

Comment: My point was that the question should be about the theoretical power of the machines---that is the interesting question here---not whether they are physically realizable. (Of course they are not equivalent to ITTMs.) I haven't yet thought enough about the inductive machines to have an answer to that part of your question.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thank you I will greatly appreciate your unbiased thoughtful opinion. This has been a concern to me for a while. Please note here too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-recursive_algorithm#Relation_to_the_Church.E2.80.93Turing_thesis. Many great ideas have failed and I do not know if this inductive turing machine idea is even at least remotely reasonable.

Comment: If an 'inductive Turing Machine' cannot say when it has obtained its result, how does one know what the result of the computation is? (Note that there's some commentary on the talk page of the linked Wikipedia article that asks the same question, with no real resolution.)

Comment: (The edit history also doesn't speak well for the subject - there's been no substantial addition to the page in nearly a decade. But that's somewhat a separate matter.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins added one more paper which cites an article of yours (once for quantum computing and another for contrasting with inductive machines).

Answer (score 14):

Let me try to answer the actual question that was asked. The [Wikipedia
page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-recursive_algorithm#Inductive_Turing_machines)
defines inductive Turing machines as follows:

> An inductive Turing machine is a definite list of well-defined
>   instructions for completing a task which, when given an initial
>   state, will proceed through a well-defined series of successive
>   states, eventually giving the final result. The difference between
>   an inductive Turing machine and an ordinary Turing machine is that
>   an ordinary Turing machine must stop when it has obtained its
>   result, while in some cases an inductive Turing machine can
>   continue to compute after obtaining the result, without stopping.

Two remarks.

1. I assume that when the description says "eventually giving
   the final result," what is meant is that there is a stage after
   which the computation is always displaying that result as output.
   This makes the concept identical to what has also been known by the term [computability-in-the-limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit), as well as other terminology. One naturally extends the concept to partial functions, by insisting that for  inputs not in the domain, what we want is for the outputs not to converge or stabilize. This is evidently the *simple* model of inductive machine; the wikipedia page makes 
   references to a hierarchy of more powerful machines.
2. Although the Wikipedia page makes numerous references to Mark
   Burgin — his name appears 24 times in the linked article — to my understanding of the history of the subject, the particular concept of computability-in-the-limit has been well understood and analyzed by computability theorists much earlier than Burgin's writings.

To my way of thinking, the main thing to say about this notion of computability is the following, which is commonly given as an exercise in computability theory courses.

**Theorem.** For any function $f$, the following are equivalent.

1. $f$ is computable by an inductive Turing machine; that is, $f$ is [computable in the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit).
2. $f$ is computable (in the usual sense) by a Turing machine
   equipped with an oracle for the halting problem.
3. The graph of $f$ is $\Sigma_2$-definable.

**Proof.** ($1\to 3$). If $f$ is computable by an inductive Turing
machine, then $f(a)=b$ if and only if there is some stage of the
inductive computation on input $a$ such that at any later stage,
the output is still $b$. This is a $\Sigma_2$ definition of the
graph of $f$.

($3\to 2$) If the graph of $f$ is $\Sigma_2$-definable, then
$f(a)=b$ just in case $\exists x\forall y\ B(x,y,a,b)$, where $B$
is $\Delta_0$. With an oracle for the halting problem and any
particular $x$, $a$ and $b$, we can ask the oracle if the $\forall
y$ condition holds. In this way, on input $a$, we can search for an
$x$ and $b$ that fulfill the condition. When found, output $b$.

($2\to 1$) If $f$ is computable with respect to an oracle for the
halting problem, then it is computable by an inductive Turing
machine: just compute better and better approximations to the
halting problem, and for each of them, use that approximation as an
oracle for the computation of $f$. This process eventually
stabilizes, because for any given input, the approximation to the
halting problem will be accurate for a long enough time to support
the correct computation of $f$. $\Box$

Note that the argument in the implication ($2\to 1$) exhibits the
feature that is central to some of the commentary about these
machines, namely, that although we can compute better and better
approximations to the halting problem, in a way that will
eventually be correct on any given instance, nevertheless we are
typically not able to recognize computably when our approximation
is correct. Thus, although we may be computing the function $f$
accurately by using that approximation, we have no way of knowing
for sure that we have the final answer.

**Corollary**. For any set $A$, the following are equivalent.

1. $A$ is decidable by an inductive Turing machine.
2. $A$ is Turing computable from the halting problem.
3. $A$ has complexity $\Delta_2$ in the arithmetic hierarchy.

**Proof.** The characteristic function of $A$ is a total function,
and so its graph is $\Sigma_2$ if and only if $A$ has complexity
$\Delta_2$. $\Box$

In this sense, yes, the so-called inductive Turing machines can compute the halting problem and therefore Hilbert's 10th problem, since that problem is equivalent to the halting problem.

But to be clear, I don't take this to show that the inductive Turing machine model refutes the Church-Turing thesis.

Unfortunately, it seems that much of the commentary and literature surrounding the claim that it does is of poor quality and in some cases mathematically empty. The discussion seems to have become distracted in the literature and gotten off track in a way; it is a pity.

One of the central achievements of computability theory is the recognition of the subtle distinction between the concept of a set being computably enumerable and it being computably decidable. The recognition that these two aspects of computability are not the same has clarified so many issues in computability. We have known since Turing that the halting problem is computably enumerable but not decidable. Meanwhile, the main arguments for inductive computability violating the Church-Turing thesis seem to my way of understanding things to amount to an attempt to erase this important distinction. After all, the halting problem itself is computable in the limit, since we can say that a program does not halt until we see that it does, and then say from that point on that it does halt. Does this show that the halting problem is computably decidable? No, I don't think so, not in any satisfactory way. And similarly I reject that claim that functions computable-in-the-limit are computable. Since these kinds of simple observations seem to resolve essentially all of the issues on this topic, I cannot recommend following much of the literature surrounding this supposed debate.

Comment: I think the entire claim of inductive turing machine is that they are non-equivalent to TMs with oracles. So from Burgin's view IMs are not same as TMs with Oracles. If you take his superrecursive algorithms book that is what it says and it is a well cited book and this is where my confusion lies.

Comment: It solves HaltP and Hilb10 without being a TM with oracle (that is the entire hypothesis if you read his comment in http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2007/03/inductive-turing-machines.html). So I am still not in clear.

Comment: Please look at article http://www.columbia.edu/itc/hs/medinfo/g6080/misc/p82-burgin.pdf in acm.

Comment: Well, I am not saying that inductive Turing machines are the same as Turing machines with an oracle for the halting problem. But I am saying that they compute the same functions.

Comment: Ok I will check on that but he also says these are realizable https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-387-26806-5_4 and https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-387-26806-5_5. So are his machines reasonable and worth studying with an open mind? Look at Martin Davis comment in wiki (he says IMs are TMs with O and not what you say).

Comment: I don't think anyone has a closed mind about the topic, and certainly the topic of computability-in-the-limit, which as far as I can tell is basically identical to the inductive TM model, is a standard part of the curriculum in computability theory and has been for decades.

Comment: For example, the topic of 2-dce, 3-dce, n-dce, $\omega$-dce, which is the study of algorithms that are allowed to change their mind about the output a specific number of times at most, counts now as completely standard classical material. So the standard treatment of computability theory already includes a robust discussion of the functions computable-in-the-limit and far more.  So everyone is on board and conversant with the actual mathematics here. What is left out are the contentious, mathematically empty claims that these concepts somehow mean that the Church-Turing thesis is refuted.

Comment: thank you very much for the finer description of algorithms. That comment did help me out more.

Answer (score 12):

> Are inductive turing machines physically realizable (at least in the same sense of realizaility of Turing machines as Intel processors with bounded RAM and one that degrades over time)?
>
> Can inductive turing machines solve the halting problem (essentially Hilbert's 10th as well)?

Others have basically answered this question, but if you're still not sure, the following exercise may help you see what's going on.

Forget about inductive Turing machines for the moment.  I have just invented  a Magic Machine that will solve the halting problem.  The Magic Machine is very simple.  If you give the Magic Machine a Turing machine T, the Magic Machine will simulate T, and will observe T while the simulation is running.  As long as the simulation continues to run, the Magic Machine keeps intoning, "It doesn't halt...it doesn't halt...it doesn't halt..."  However, if and when the simulated T halts, the Magic Machine suddenly changes its tune and says, "It halts!  It halts!  It halts!"

As I said, I claim that my Magic Machine is physically realizable and solves the halting problem.  Do you believe me?  If so, I will sell you one for the low, low price of $1 million.

If you don't think that my Magic Machine is "a physically realizable machine that solves the halting problem," then see if you can articulate clearly *why* you aren't inclined to buy it.  If you can, then you should be able to articulate equally clearly why no inductive Turing machine is "a physically realizable machine that solves the halting problem."

Comment: Thanks, Timothy, this is very nice. I was trying to convey the same example in the last paragraph of my answer, but you did so much more colorfully!

Comment: @timothychow is this also what you have in mind 'A simple inductive Turing machine produces its results without
stopping. It is possible that in the sequence of computations after
some step, the word on the output tape is not changing, while the
simple inductive Turing machine continues working. This word,
which is not changing is the result Thus the which is not changing, is the result. Thus, the simple inductive simple inductive
Turing machine does not halt...'? http://www.idt.mdh.se/kurser/cd5560/12_11/LECTURES/pdf/InductiveTuringMachines-MarkBurgin.pdf.

Comment: @timothychow in his book he says 'Although many still believe that only recursive algorithms exist and that only some of them are realizable, there are many situations in which people actually work with superrecursive algorithms' and continues examples of superrecursive algorithms include ITMs (https://books.google.com/books?id=47SKAD5HvXsC&pg=PR9&dq=%22INDUCTIVE+TURING+MACHINES%22+realizable+burgin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuvfSUk7LVAhVKw1QKHZXODx0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22INDUCTIVE%20TURING%20MACHINES%22%20realizable%20burgin&f=false).

Comment: @timothychow here he might inductive TMs and limit TMs https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fb01/017619b264e13f2694a853958edf75585593.pdf (I am not sure though). 'Such big networks as INTERNET give another important example of a situation in which conventional algorithms are not adequate. Network functioning is organized by algorithms embodied in a multiplicity of different programs. It is generally assumed that any computer program, is a conventional, i.e., recursive algorithm..

Comment: ..However, a recursive algorithm has to
stop to give a result, but we cannot say that a network shuts down, then something is wrong and it gives no results. Consequently, recursive algorithms turn out to be inadequate.'. So he envisions internet as a machine which gives results without halting.

Comment: no i won't. but i will not hae to buy medicne for headaches and when i teach something to students i will make more sense.

Comment: @777 : Instead of constantly quoting other people, I recommend that you answer the questions yourself.  Specifically, do you believe that my Magic Machine is "a physically realizable machine that solves the halting problem"? If not, why not? If anything is physically realizable, surely the Magic Machine is. And it seems to do as good a job as any inductive Turing machine at "solving the halting problem."  Doesn't it? Please answer for yourself instead of quoting someone else.

Comment: @TimothyChow yes it does solve the halting problem but then is the inductive TM some cheap trick to avoid oracles to solve the halting problem?

Comment: @777 : Ah, so you *do* think that my Magic Machine is physically realizable and solves the halting problem? Then why aren't you paying me $1 million?  Forget about the inductive TM, which it seems you're unsure about.  You understand my Magic Machine, and I can build it, and it solves a problem that everybody else seems to say is unsolvable.  If you can't come up with the cash, I'm prepared to offer you a discount.

Comment: @TimothyChow no i did not say it is realizable.

Comment: @777 : Just to clarify, my Magic Machine is *not* an oracle.  I can code it up in a few minutes in any programming language and it will run exactly as advertised.  No tricks.  So why do you say it is not realizable?

Comment: @timothychow ok then what is the big deal about ITMs if they are just limit machines?

Comment: @777 : It would help if you would answer my question. Why do you say that my Magic Machine is not realizable?

Comment: @TimothyChow I don't want to wait till i die.

Comment: @TimothyChow ok have you looked at the comment here 
http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2007/03/inductive-turing-machines.html? he says the machine does not have to halt at all 'However, M can also obtain a result in a different way. Namely, when at some step of computation, the word written in the output tape stops changing, then this word is also the final result of the simplest inductive Turing machine M'. It seems your magic machine halts. right?

Comment: @TimothyChow He also clarifies on 'limit' and also disses some of 'incompetent' comments there by stating 'In spite of some incompetent comments, inductive Turing machines have much higher computing power than inductive inference machine and limit partial recursive functions.'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63135/discussion-between-timothy-chow-and-777).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins does this have anything to do with this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_computation?

Comment: The darpa funding page https://www.nextbigfuture.com/2012/04/super-turing-ai-gets-development.html (although this is not a formal reference it quotes Burgin).

Comment: @TimothyChow:  At the risk of sounding stupid, a question: are the Godel numbers for the arithmetical hierarchy typed, that is, say for $\Sigma_n$, $\Pi_n$, and $\Delta_n$ for some fixed $n$, there exist functions in $\Sigma_n$, $\Pi_n$, $\Delta_n$ whose Godel numbers, if presented as inputs of functions in $\Sigma_{n-1}$, $\Pi_{n-1}$, $\Delta_{n-1}$, would (in the words of Harley Rogers Jr. -- see pg. 25 of his _Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability_) make $f$ in $\Sigma_{n-1}$, $\Pi_{n-1}$, $\Delta_{n-1}$ either "undefined" for that input, or, "gives erroneous

Comment: (cont.) information" (as an output for that particular input)?  I ask because it would be reasonable to assume (?) that your "Magic Machine" has a Godel number and therefore be acceptable as an input for a universal Turing machine (which Burgin says is a subroutine in his Inductive Turing Machines).  Would the universal Turing machine have a definable output if given your "Magic Machine's" Godel number as its input?  Would it spit out "erroneous information"?  Are there 'generalized Turing-type machine' representations for each level of the Arithmetical Hierarchy?

Comment: That was Hartley Rogers, Jr.  Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 10):

This is *not* an answer to the OP's question, and is a bit of a tangent. 
But perhaps relevant concerning the physical realizability issue raised by Joel.

I just today heard a talk on a "Fold-and-Cut Machine." 
This leads to a physical model equi-powerful 
to a nondeterministic Turing machine:

> "a *fold-and-cut machine* can decide a 3-SAT instance with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses using $O(nm+m^2)$ operations (...), showing that the machine is at least as powerful as a nondeterministic Turing machine."
>
> An, Byoungkwon, Erik D. Demaine, Martin L. Demaine, and Jason S. Ku. "Computing 3SAT on a Fold-and-Cut Machine."
>   [Full CCCG Proceedings download](http://2017.cccg.ca/proceedings/CCCG2017.pdf),
>   p.208ff for the article.

One folds a strip of paper a polynomial number of times, 
snips it to produce holes, 
rearranges the folding, 
and then looks to see if you can see all the way through the
rearranged folding. You can iff the 3-SAT instance is solvable.

---

[image: SATholes]

---

Comment: Note, however, that myth that you can only fold a piece of paper seven times has already been busted: https://youtu.be/kRAEBbotuIE

Comment: Reminds me of Lehmer's photoelectric number sieve, http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/lehmermachine.jpg and http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/Mike-Williams-Lehmer.html

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following paper, written by A. Steven Younger, Emmett Redd, Hava Siegelmann, and Conrad Bell:

> "A Physical Machine Based on a Super-Turing Computational Model" [found under title on the Web].

I quote the Abstract verbatim:

> We present evidence that the Turing Machine is too restrictive a model to sufficiently describe the computation of our analog computer and, therefore a more conprehensive model is needed.  We report on the construction of a prototype, the Optical Analog Recurrent Neural Network (OpticARRN), and experimental results showing that it performs computations which are beyond those of computers based on the Turing machine.  we conclude that the behavior of OpticARRN is better described by the super-Turing computational model proposed by Siegelmann.  To the best of our knowledge, this is the first application of analog recurrent neural networks realized in a physical computer based on this model.

(Suffice it to say, I leave the judgement as to the truth or falsity of the claim(s) made in the Abstract and the paper to the Reader.)

What I find personally (for what that's worth) interesting in this paper is this particular claim (found in Section 3, "Testing for Computation Beyond the Turing Limit"):

> In order to test super-Turing computation, a suitable problem must be found.  In this case, the answer came from the area of chaotic systems.  The dynamics of chaos are both aperiodic and defined on a continuous phase space.  As such, they cannot be mimicked by a Turing machine [Siegelmann, H. (1998). *Neural Networks and Analog Computation Beyond the Turing Limit*.  Boston: Birkhauser(p. 155)].

It is the validity of this claim that (seemingly) makes or breaks the experiment. Also, the reader should pay particular attention to their methodology for the interpretation of the experimental data.

Note that the experimental setup is shown in figure 1 on pg. 4 of the paper (at least on the copy of the paper I found on the Web).

Comment: Why the downvote?